Is plausibility more fundamental than probability?
There seem to be many contexts in which it makes sense to define a probability or atleast an approximate one and attach that to a certain proposition. If that is very low, it is often taken to be implausible.
For example, it seems to make sense to say “it is improbable that I will throw 20 sixes in a row” but also “it is implausible that I will throw 20 sixes in a row.” It seems easy to define a probability in this case because of actual data in regards to dice rolls or merely the structure of a dice
But there are certain cases in which hypotheses seem to be implausible even without a defined probability. For example, if someone says “well, actually, John didn’t kill michael despite finding his fingerprints on his body and finding evidence of his intention to murder. An invisible, undetectable goblin or being or god who was controlling John through unknowable means killed Michael.” many would find this extremely implausible. And yet, it would seem to make less sense to attach a probability to this. How often has an invisible goblin or being done things? What data can we look at to attach a figure to this kind of explanation at work, even approximately?
Does this mean plausibility is more fundamental than probability? How does one talk about the former without the latter in a still reasonable fashion?

Great question. I'd say yes but perhaps it's better to answer like that.

Is the first answer truly completely AI? I am in absolute shock

Yes. The link to Leonard Koan conversation is legit. I am preparing a report on Leonard Koan.

Thomas Aquinas Emulator prefers not to say 'yes'. Instead, he dissects the argument methodologically.

@MichalRyszardWojcik - Mesmerizing, indeed. Your brain children are growing up fast.

If by "more fundamental" you mean more universally applicable then yes, plausibility is more that than quantified probability. And it is so because pairwise comparisons can be reasonably made even when there is no universal scale to which everything can be related, and/or with less information than such relating would require. Partial order is more universally applicable than full order, vague terms are more universally applicable than precise terms. And not just for plausibility/probability.

Often, what we do in science, mathematics and logic, is to take a naive, pre-theoretic concept and work out how to turn it into something precise and formal. For example, in physics we may start with a naive concept of inertia: heavy things take more effort than light things to get moving and to make stop once they are moving. With a bit of work we can convert this into a precise and formal concept of momentum. In mathematics, we might start with the naive concept of a collection and develop it into formal theories of sets, bags and sequences. In logic and computation, we might start with the naive concept of what it means to perform a computation and develop a formal theory of computation using precise concepts such as Turing machines and recursive functions.
Plausibility is a naive, pre-theoretic concept. We have an intuitive understanding that some propositions are more plausible than others. Probability theory is one way of turning this naive concept into something formal and precise. Probability theory is axiomatisable and has a calculus that tells us how to compute one probability from others. Under the Bayesian interpretation, probability can be understood as a rational degree of credence in a proposition. Probability provides a way to quantify uncertainty and this is an important input into decision theory. We constantly have to make decisions with uncertain information, and we can make better decisions if we can quantify that uncertainty.
Sometimes we have known unknowns and we can do a pretty good job of quantifying them. We know how to put a number to the probability of a dice roll. We know how to assign a probability to the presence of oil when drilling an exploration well. We know how to calculate a probability that a person will die in the next twelve months.
Sometimes we have unknown unknowns and we have no satisfactory way to quantify them. This is called Knightian uncertainty. We have to live with it but we cannot compute it. A rough rule of thumb for determining whether something qualifies as a known unknown is to ask whether we can insure against the risk. If an insurance company can write an insurance policy and stay in business then it strongly suggests that we can quantify that risk adequately.
Uncertainties in forensic science involving fingerprints and DNA evidence, etc., can be quantified. The uncertainty involved in assessing whether a goblin or an alien caused something cannot.
So plausibility is not more fundamental than probability, but rather probability is one helpful way of making plausibility precise. But there is no guarantee that we will always be able to quantify an uncertainty.

Great answer but the last paragraph seems to be contradictory. If probability is one way of quantifying plausibility, does that not then directly imply that plausibility is more fundamental (if probability is a form of it)? Although I guess this is just a semantic quip and not too important

@Kelly - I don't think "X is a quantification of Y" means that Y is more fundamental than X. To me, that's like saying that "Heaviness is more fundamental than weight." It's possible to show (using a balance) that one thing is heavier than another without knowing the weights of the two objects, but we still understand that it is the same fundamental forces at work, and we just have an inexact versus an exact way of measuring it. (In the case of probability, I would call the fundamental force at play "uncertainty.")

If something is not quantifiable, that usually implies it has no evidence going for it. And it seems irrational to assign anything but the lowest probability to something that has no evidence. (e.g. goblins).

@Syed I wouldn't go that far. Something might be difficult to put a value on because we have too little quantitative information about it. Such things are called imponderables. It does not imply that they have very low probability. Someone might claim that it is plausible to suppose that there is intelligent alien life somewhere in the known universe, but we really have no idea how to put a probability on it.

@Bumble sure, I should have been more clear that I only think it’s rational to attach an infinitesimal probability to something that has no current evidence for it. One could argue that this doesn’t apply to life outside earth since we implicitly have some level of evidence for it, even if real (the evidence being our own existence). This wouldn’t apply to the existence of goblins for example

As a rule, human minds operate in a narrative mode; we conceptualize things in terms of stories about ourselves, or others, or the world. almost every person and object in our lives is couched in an assortment of narratives about what we do with them, where we go with them, what purposes they serve, what problems they present, etc. With training and practice we learn to think analytically — in terms of impersonal structures and events — but that is a more rarified form of cognition. And as a rule we use analytic modes to build better (more useful or effective) stories. Analysis produces data or constructs that intrinsically lack meaning, so they must be incorporated into meaning-bearing narratives to make sense.
'Probability' is an analytic concept; 'plausibility' is a narrative concept. For instance, I can say that there is a 42.26% probability of getting a pair if dealt five cards; that's data. But to give that data meaning I'd end up saying something narrative like: "It's plausible that guy drew a pair given the way he's betting." The first is just a dry number, while the second encases that number in a story about what's happening in the world.
Generally speaking, people want to know what's happening. We make up stories about what's going on around us, and we have a vested interest in knowing whether those stories are plausibly true or ridiculous fantasies. Analytical modes like probabilities can sometimes help clarify how likely some story is, but most people use analytic modes to supplement and inform their intuitions and feelings, not to override them. I mean, if I tell someone that there is a chance  that they are going to die if they do a certain activity, that probability might scare them off because they see death as a 'plausible' outcome, or it might be worked into a story in which 'overcoming the odds' is a 'plausible' outcome that makes the activity more interesting and enjoyable. It's a question of how one takes the raw data and imbues it with meaning.

With the greatest respect, you are comparing two loose abstract nouns whose meanings overlap considerably in that abuse of language known as everyday speech. You are also asking whether one is more 'fundamental', implying that it is in some way a sort of foundational concept for the other. Ignoring for once the scope to make a cheap joke, in this case about avoiding the charge of talking out of my fundament, I think the most charitable and constructive response I can make to your question is to sharpen the distinction between the two pivotal words, which I will attempt to do as follows.
Plausible is an indication of possibility, whereas probable is an indication of likelihood. A thing can be plausible regardless of whether it is probable, so in that sense plausibility is more general than probability. Conversely, a thing cannot be probable if it is implausible, so in that sense you might say that plausibility is a precondition for probable. Whether a precondition is always a foundation, or fundamental, is a more... well, fundamental question.
